# Plot audio waveform and spectrogram overlap

Tags: python, audio, wave, spectrogram

I am working with audio using librosa, and I need to plot the spectrogram and waveform in the same display.

My code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 9))

plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.title('Spectrogram')
librosa.display.specshow(stft_db, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')

plt.subplot(212)
plt.title('Audioform')
librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr=sr)
```

Using this code I get this plot

[image]

But I need something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to librosa, you're able to provide the display methods with an axes to draw the item on, [specshow](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html#librosa.display.specshow), [waveplot](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.display.waveplot.html). I'd recommend defining your matplotlib figure and subplots outright, and then giving librosa the axes to plot them on.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 9)) #This setups the figure
ax1 = fig.subplots() #Creates the Axes object to display one of the plots
ax2 = ax1.twinx() #Creates a second Axes object that shares the x-axis

librosa.display.specshow(stft_db, x_axis='time', y_axis='log', ax=ax1)
librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr=sr, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

There might be some more formatting to be done to get the desired look, I'd recommend taking a look at [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html) from matplotlib, for a similar shared axes plot.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the quick response! That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using subplots use the same axes of a single plot to display both the graphs.

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 9))
ax = librosa.display.specshow(stft_db, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr=sr, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```